# jQuery code fail (on all browsers)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am currently running a jQuery/PHP code. In the PHP, I use a while loop to look in my MySQL for the persons *login*. If the code finds the user logged in in the database it displays a queue where it pulls each *steam id*, contacts *steam api*, retrieves each steam avatar and displays it on the widget. The jQuery executes a code that loads a certain `div` of the page every 10 seconds.

Everything works when you are clicked on to the page however, when you click off of the page in another tab you get an *"Oh snap"* error in Chrome. I tried the code in Mozilla and Internet Explorer and it got an error there as well. I originally thought that it was because it took longer than 10 seconds to connect to *steam api* but I tested it when I was not logged in so it was not contacting *steam api* but I was still getting the error.

jQuery:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(function($){
             setInterval(function(){
             $('#header').load('button1.php');
             }, 10000);
          });
    </script>
   </head>
  <body>
```

PHP:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT text FROM names order by id limit 10");
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT text FROM names order by id limit 10");
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $name = $rows['text'];
   if($Steam64id == $name)
   {
      while($rowss = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
      {
        $names = $rowss['text'];
        echo"<br>";
        include"avatar2.php";
      }
   }
   else
   {
   }
}
```

avatar2.php:

```
<?php
$response = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/? key=xxx&steamids={$names}&format=json";
$middle = (file_get_contents($response));
$json = json_decode($middle, true);
$a = $json['response']['players'][0]['avatarfull'];
$b = $json['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
echo "<font size='2'>";
print_r($b);
echo "<br>";
echo"<img src='$a' alt=''height='42' width='42'>";
?>
```

Any help here would be great. This is my first time using Javascript besides a show/hide table. Thanks.

Comment: your HTML page might be missing `<div id="header"></div>` nevermind didn't notice the codes all work fine for you, yeah it's a HTML Parsing/rendering issue 100%.

Comment: Just tested your code while being in another chrome tab.. I have no issues at all. http://jsfiddle.net/Me8Pq/

Comment: Thats wierd.  Anyways, I believe I fixed it by adding 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"> to add my pages although I don't know why it wasn't working before.  Could it be that since it kept going through the while loop it kept accumulating more and more data until it couldn't handle it?

Comment: Doubt it, it's not like it stops working but keeps refilling header even if you are in a different chrome tab. Best to figure out how to see what errors chrome encountered to get the error, probably error logs somewhere stored.

Answer (score 0):

**How to fix Google Chrome’s Aw, Snap! error message when loading websites**

1. http://www.ghacks.net/2013/05/23/how-to-fix-google-chromes-aw-snap-error-message-when-loading-websites/
2. http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/google-chrome-aw-snap.html
3. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/aw-snap-error/5e33319b-5a05-4a79-bf17-b7cf9b51503a

Comment: I don't think this is just a google chrome error-I think it is a problem with a code but I don't know where.  When I tried the code on IE and mozilla it still failed.